# React Google Map with DirectionsRendered, how to pass directions props?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I have a problem with react-google-maps map with DirectionRenderer.
I tried to pass directions props in many ways but I always get this error:

*InvalidValueError: setDirections: in property routes: not an Array*

I defined like below:

```
state= {
      a: new google.maps.LatLng(41.8507300, -87.6512600),
      b: new google.maps.LatLng(41.8525800, -87.6514100)
};
```

and then passed here but got the error described

```
<MapWithADirectionsRenderer 
       directions={ how to pass here? } />
```

I have also another problem:  I get this error :

*You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.*

I included script tag to api google in public_html/index.html and also on the component MapWithADirectionsRenderer on googleMapURL requested params like in the official example (https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#directionsrenderer).
I cannot remove the script on index.html because if I remove it I get the 'google undefined error' .  I used /*global google */ at the start of the file the I use 'new google.maps..ecc like described on another stack overflow post.

Comment: Hi, Are you using react-google-map package?

Comment: If Yes,  from where do you import <MapWithADirectionsRenderer>,
Please let me know

Comment: @neelima is was a custom component: a simple google map using a direction renderer. Check it out here https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#directionsrenderer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved like below by modifying standard code from

```
DirectionsService.route({
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(41.8507300, -87.6512600),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(41.8525800, -87.6514100),
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  }, (result, status) => {
    etc etc
  });
```

to

```
DirectionsService.route({
    origin: this.props.origin,
    destination: this.props.destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  }, (result, status) => {
     etc etc
  });
```

and the pass origin and destination props like so

```
<MapWithADirectionsRenderer
    origin={this.state.origin} destination={this.state.destination} />
```

Now it works good!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fresh project and test the following files:

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import MapWithADirectionsRenderer from './MapWithADirectionsRenderer'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myArray: [
        {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        {lat: -24.397, lng: 140.644},
        {lat: -14.397, lng: 130.644},
      ]
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.myArray.map((a,index) => {
            return <MapWithADirectionsRenderer
              direction={a}
              key={index}
            />
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

MapWithADirectionsRenderer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker} from "react-google-maps"

export default class MapWithADirectionsRenderer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyMapComponent
          key={this.props.key}
          isMarkerShown
          googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
          loadingElement={<div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
          containerElement={<div style={{height: `400px`}}/>}
          mapElement={<div style={{height: `50%`}}/>}
          direction={this.props.direction}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={8}
    defaultCenter={{lat: props.direction.lat, lng: props.direction.lng}}
  >
    {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}}/>}
  </GoogleMap>
));
```

Comment: I tried but I get this error on console:  Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: @alberto-battistini, Can you test the updated code please.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. In my opinion it's wrong to map each element of myArray rendering <MapWithADirectionsRenderer /> for each one.